# Побитовые операции. Преобразование старшего байта, чтобы его двоичное представление стало палиндромом (C++)

Tags: c++

Дано короткое целое неотрицательное число. Преобразовать
старший байт числа таким образом, чтобы его двоичное
представление стало палиндромом.
Число представлено в виде 16-ричной сс. (ввод и вывод)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
 
typedef unsigned short ushort;
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    ushort num, upp = 0;
    cout << "Введите число в 16-ичной системе: ";
    cin >> hex >> num;
    cin.get();
    ushort low = num & 15;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if (low & (1 << 16 - i))
        {
            upp += (1 << (16 - i));
        }
    }
    ushort res = low + 16 * upp;
 
    cout << "Число преобразовано в: " << hex << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

При вводе числа "00FF", программа выдаёт результат "EF" - что неправильно. Проблема во всём цикле, не очень понимаю, что не так.

Comment: Вам надо работать с байтом. А, например, `low + 16 * upp;` — никак не с байтом работа. Да и сама логика хромает...

Comment: Код не мой. я потом сам заметил что число не совпадает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ushort low = num & 0xFF;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   upp = upp << 1;
   upp |= (low >> i) & 1;
}
ushort res = low + 0x100 * upp;
```

[тест](https://onlinegdb.com/7tgUyiAtB)

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант, без цикла

```
ushort pal(ushort x)
{
    ushort y = x & 0xFF;
    x = (x&0x55)<<1|(x&0xAA)>>1;
    x = (x&0x33)<<2|(x&0xCC)>>2;
    x = (x&0x0F)<<4|(x&0xF0)>>4;
    return y|(x<<8);
}
```